# FreeDOS installer hangs at 0% base/kernel

Tags: freedos

i am trying to install FreeDOS but when i try to install it hangs at 0% base/kernel. Does anyone know why this happens? Please help if you can, thank you.

Comment: Please clarify your specific problem or provide additional details to highlight exactly what you need. As it's currently written, it's hard to tell exactly what you're asking.

Comment: I was trying to install FreeDOS from USB to my computer, i downloaded FreeDOS USB from FreeDOS website and wrote it to my disk using rufus. When going through the installer i format the drive, choose keyboard layout and so on, but then when the install begins, it gets stuck at 0% ''Installing packages'' Base/kernel. Do you know why?